# Calculus power series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Hi could anyone help me to solve this. express the function $\int_x ^0 (\sin(t^2)\cdot \cos(t^2))$ as a power series.   Because there is two trigo identies I do not know how to combine them to form a power series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(t^2)\cos(t^2)=\frac12\sin(2t^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{___}\cdot t^{4n+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly $\sin(t^2)\cos(t^2)=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t^2}$, and expanding this as a power series we have:

$\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2t^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Thus:

$\int_0^x\sin(t^2)\cos(t^2)dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_x^0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2t^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dt=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_x^0\frac{(-1)^n(2t^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dt$